# Split value from a total row to multiple other rows until the sum reaches the value of the total row in REDSHIFT

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d475ac598abc2518fff4b714bd2f3b32)**

```
CREATE TABLE inbound (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    campaign VARCHAR,
    expected_inbound_date DATE,
    expected_inbound_quantity DECIMAL,
    received_inbound_quantity DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO inbound
(campaign, expected_inbound_date, expected_inbound_quantity, received_inbound_quantity)
VALUES 
('C001', '2022-05-03', '500', '0'),
('C001', '2022-05-03', '800', '0'),
('C001', '2022-05-03', '400', '0'),
('C001', '2022-05-03', '200', '0'),
('C001', NULL, '0', '700'),

('C002', '2022-08-20', '3000', '0'),
('C002', '2022-08-20', '5000', '0'),
('C002', '2022-08-20', '2800', '0'),
('C002', NULL, '0', '4000');
```

**Expected Result**

```
campaign |  expected_inbound_date |  expected_inbound_quantity  |  split_received_inbound_quantity
---------|------------------------|-----------------------------|----------------------------------
  C001   |        2022-05-03      |             200             |          200
  C001   |        2022-05-03      |             400             |          400
  C001   |        2022-05-03      |             500             |          100
  C001   |        2022-05-03      |             800             |            0
  C001   |                        |                             |          700
---------|------------------------|-----------------------------|----------------------------------
  C002   |       2022-08-20       |           3.800             |         3.800
  C002   |       2022-08-20       |           5.000             |           200
  C002   |       2022-08-20       |           2.800             |             0
  C002   |                        |                             |         4.000
```

---

I want to split the `received_inbound_quantity` to each row of the `expected_inbound_quantity` until the total of the `received_inbound_quantity` is reached. 
With reference to the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71749840/split-value-from-a-total-row-to-multiple-other-rows-until-the-sum-reaches-the-va) I tried to go with this solution:

```
SELECT
i.campaign AS campaign,
i.expected_inbound_date AS expected_inbound_date,
i.expected_inbound_quantity AS expected_inbound_quantity,
i.received_inbound_quantity AS received_inbound_quantity,

(SELECT 
   GREATEST(
     LEAST(i.expected_inbound_quantity, 
          (SELECT 
           SUM(i3.received_inbound_quantity) 
           FROM inbound i3 
           WHERE i.campaign = i3.campaign)  -
           
            (
                SELECT 
                t1.cumulated_value AS cumulated_value 
                FROM
                
                   (SELECT
                    i2.campaign, 
                    i2.expected_inbound_date, 
                    i2.expected_inbound_quantity, 
                    i2.received_inbound_quantity,
                    SUM(i2.expected_inbound_quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY i2.campaign ORDER BY i2.expected_inbound_date, i2.expected_inbound_quantity, i2.received_inbound_quantity ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS cumulated_value
                    FROM inbound i2
                    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4) t1
                    
                WHERE (t1.campaign, t1.expected_inbound_date, t1.expected_inbound_quantity, t1.received_inbound_quantity) = (i.campaign, i.expected_inbound_date, i.expected_inbound_quantity, i.received_inbound_quantity)
            )
            
        ),
        0
   )
) AS split

FROM inbound i
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4
```

---

However, in redshift I get error:

```
Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet;
```

How do I need to modify the query to also make it work in redshift?

Comment: Does redshift accept CTE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions are your friend.  When you have a query that compares rows you should first look to window functions on Redshift.  This simpler, cleaner, and faster than any self joining pattern.

```
select 
  campaign,
  expected_inbound_date,
  expected_inbound_quantity,
  received_inbound_quantity,
  case when (inbound_total - inbound_sum) >= 0 then expected_inbound_quantity
       else case when (expected_inbound_quantity + inbound_total - inbound_sum) >= 0 then expected_inbound_quantity + inbound_total - inbound_sum
                else 0 end
    end as split

from (SELECT
  campaign,
  expected_inbound_date,
  expected_inbound_quantity,
  received_inbound_quantity,
  sum(expected_inbound_quantity) over (partition by campaign order by expected_inbound_date, expected_inbound_quantity) as inbound_sum,
  max(received_inbound_quantity) over (partition by campaign) as inbound_total

  FROM inbound i
) subq
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4;
```

Updated fiddle here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2381abdf5a90a997a4f05b809c892c40

When you port this to Redshift you may want to convert the CASE statements to DECODE() functions as these are more readable IMHO.

PS. Thank you for setting up the fiddle as this greatly speeds up providing an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation. I only had to add ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW in the window function of the sum(expected_inbound_quantity) to make it work in Redshift.

Comment: Here is the fiddle for it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f475f8721edb3a970c23a2f61d2fcaf4

Comment: Yes, good catch.